# hide elements not inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a [website](http://dundaah.com/docs/sun.html) (click on red fist). It has a search function. If you click on the search it fails to occupy 100% window height and you can still scroll content not inside the 'morphsearch'. Where am I going wrong?

```js
//morphSearch code
(function() {
  var morphSearch = document.getElementById('morphsearch'),
    input = morphSearch.querySelector('input.morphsearch-input'),
    ctrlClose = morphSearch.querySelector('span.morphsearch-close'),
    ctrlClose2 = morphSearch.querySelector('span.morphsearch-close2'),
    isOpen = isAnimating = false,
    // show/hide search area
    toggleSearch = function(evt) {
      // return if open and the input gets focused
      if (evt.type.toLowerCase() === 'focus' && isOpen) return false;

      var offsets = morphsearch.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (isOpen) {
        classie.remove(morphSearch, 'open');

        // trick to hide input text once the search overlay closes 
        // todo: hardcoded times, should be done after transition ends
        if (input.value !== '') {
          setTimeout(function() {
            classie.add(morphSearch, 'hideInput');
            setTimeout(function() {
              classie.remove(morphSearch, 'hideInput');
              input.value = '';
            }, 300);
          }, 500);
        }

        input.blur();
      } else {
        classie.add(morphSearch, 'open');
      }
      isOpen = !isOpen;
    };

  // events
  input.addEventListener('focus', toggleSearch);
  ctrlClose.addEventListener('click', toggleSearch);
  ctrlClose2.addEventListener('click', toggleSearch);
  // esc key closes search overlay
  // keyboard navigation events
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
    var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
    if (keyCode === 27 && isOpen) {
      toggleSearch(ev);
    }
  });


  /***** for demo purposes only: don't allow to submit the form *****/
  morphSearch.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
})();
```

```css
.morphsearch {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: min-height, width, top, right;
  transition-property: min-height, width, top, right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
.morphsearch.open {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="morphsearch" class="morphsearch">
  <form id="searchForm" class="morphsearch-form" method="post">
    <input id="s" class="morphsearch-input" type="search" placeholder="Search Dundaah..." />
    <input class="morphsearch-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
  </form>
  <div id="resultsDiv" class="morphsearch-content2"></div>
  <span class="morphsearch-close"></span>
  <span class="morphsearch-close2"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hello can you tell me one thing?
What you want actually?
You dont want to see other content when search is open?

Comment: yes, I only want the morphsearch to be visible and scroll-able till it's closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your CSS as follows and try again:

```
.morphsearch.open {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: nice it works, but i have a results div for the search results that's not scroll-able after I add this code.

Comment: dude! perfect! seriously, thanks! been troubling me for a while.. is there a way to cancel the main scroll bar for the hidden content?

Comment: yes you can add css to body when that search page open

Comment: i've tride body.morphsearch.open{overflow-y:hidden;} to no avail

Comment: it is not like that but you have to add css using jquery when search open

Answer (score 0):

While opening your search, you should give your `<html>` and `<body>` a new class, e.g. `hideoverflow` and remove overflow in your CSS:

```
.hideoverflow {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Just don't forget to toggle the class when closing the searchform again.